# How does the smarty assign function work?

Tags: php, smarty, assign

The code inside an HTML file is like this:

```
{assign var="url" value="/?user&q=code/approve/myapp"}
```

when loading page, the server returns error code 500.

Comment: got crazy, even {assign var="url" value="abc"} doesn't work

Comment: I changed the language to be more readable

Comment: you have to figure out the error message (e.g.: from the logs). `500` doesn't tell us much...

Comment: thank u, I have solved my problem by another way. but this question still hasn't been solved.

Comment: I'm pretty new to smarty. how to see the logs? I use php+smarty+html. should I find the log from php log?

Comment: Does the 500 error have anything actually to do with this line of code?

Comment: Yes, Apache and/or PHP logs is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
{assign var="url" value="/?user&q=code/approve/myapp"}
```

It is throwing you the 500 error because your php cannot process the request. You need to have $_GET function to get those values and most importantly your code should be

```
{assign var="url" value="somefile.php?user&q=code/approve/myapp"}
```

You can't end it with / and start immediately with ?

Example

**This will output JSON Data**

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk
```

**This will throw error**

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/?q=London,uk
```

Comment: *"You can't end it with / and start immediately with ?"* - Oh yes, you can. It's a perfectly valid URL, and an appropriately configured web server will even serve it just fine. Also, this Smarty tag shouldn't be evaluating the URL at all, it shouldn't matter at all what the actual value is.